# Firedac ODBC and Ingres database - "API function cannot be called in the current state"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, firedac, ingres

i have problem with reading data from Ingres database by Delphi Firedac(ODBC).
I can connect to Ingres database (no exception throw) but when i try to read data by FDQuery i got:

```
"API function cannot be called in the current state"
```

With the same connection string and dbExpress(ODBC) i have no problems with reading data by sql statements.

I know that dbExpress is much simpler and maybe Firedac try to read/set something more in ODBC driver which make problems.
I reported issue in Embarcadero Quality Portal https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11536 but without any response

May be someone know what to do to be able to work with Ingres database and Firedac

Answer (score 2):

Problem was resolved by help by Dmitry Arefiev from Embarcadero
adding to connection parameters

```
ODBCAdvanced=SELECTLOOPS=N
```

fix problem at all

Comment: I added SELECTLOOPS=N to the relevant config section in the odbc.ini file, and that also worked for me. (Just to clarify I was using node-js connecting to an ingres database, and was getting the same error)